# How do I interpret Entity Relationship Diagrams?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, erd

I just learnt about ERDs, how to generate them and their purpose today. I tried generating to chart the structure of the database of my website using pygraphviz, pyparsing and pydot but I realised I have no idea how to read this cool-looking diagram.

Can anyone help me interpret this? Any help is very much appreciated!!

Here is the [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/143pLVL07GOZpqUrM5C5nq5kkPMK_PuaH/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one tiny part of your picture cropped so I can actually read the text in the image.

[image: Test Project]

Each block with the dark box at the top is one of your database tables.

The `Message` table (entity) is probably the most reasonable one to talk about.  All of the columns of the Message table are listed in the box.

The lines connecting boxes are the relationships between the tables.  One of the lines points to the `Recipient` table(entity).  That entity is connected by the `received_messages` code.

Hence, the diagram is called an entity-relationship diagram.  Here's a more detailed explanation I found: [What is Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)?](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/data-modeling/what-is-entity-relationship-diagram/;WWWSESSIONID=F1883F031148FFD92889582D90A8D9AD.www1)

Generally, you draw independent portions of your database in separate diagrams so it doesn't get so confusing.